# free(): double free detected in tcache 2 when trying to delete a non binary tree

Tags: c, data-structures, free

I'm having issues deleting the following tree:

```
typedef struct Comment {
    const char* id;
    const char* user;
    const char* date;
    const char* commentText;
    const char* likes;
    int numberOfReplies;
    struct Comment* cTreeArr[100];
} *CTree, Comment;
```

I ensure that the tree is working properly and that every index that doesn't have a comment is set to NULL.
I'm trying to use the following function to delete the tree:

```
void freeCTree(CTree cTree) {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        if (cTree->cTreeArr[i] != NULL) {
            freeCTree(cTree->cTreeArr[i]);
        } else break;
    }
    free(cTree);
}
```

Every time I try to run it I get this error:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Additional info:
The original program is made using the flex lexical analyzer.
It receives an HTML file from a news website page and extracts the comments.
It creates a tree with the main comment and it's children and stores it in a tree data structure.
When the tree is complete it prints in a JSON format and proceeds to next main comment repeating the process.

If I just set de cTree variable to NULL when I finish a comment tree, the program works perfectly outputting the desired result. However the memory used isn't deallocated.

Comment: If you printf() every address returned by malloc, and every address you try to free, you just have to look backwards to see where it was already freed.

Comment: Is it possible initializing your tree went wrong and a node is actually present in several branches?

Comment: That's it. I checked now and for 262 total comments the output only has 95 original and the rest are duplicated. There is nothing wrong with freeCTree. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that cTreeArr doesn't have a NULL terminator?

Comment: Ignore what I said in the last comment. I tested a previous version of my program and every comment is actually unique. I printed every pointer created by malloc and they are also unique. 
Every element of cTreeArr is NULL if it doens't have a comment. I assign to NULL when I malloc.